# error message with apt-get update command

Tags: apt, updates

When I update my system, I get the following errors:

> Fetched 316 B in 22s (14 B/s)
>   Reading package lists... Done
>
> W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6AF0E1940624A220

Please someone suggest me a solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to download the missing keys using this command in your case:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 6AF0E1940624A220
```

For the CDRom errors check [This thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/478228/update-information-outdated-failed-to-fetch-cdrom)

Comment: Given link solved it partially but, still I get the following error.                                                
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6AF0E1940624A220

Comment: What output does this command give:

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 6AF0E1940624A220`

Als try running `apt-get update` after running the previous command.

Comment: Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.dQhWdGIu31 --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 6AF0E1940624A220
gpg: requesting key 0624A220 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
?: keyserver.ubuntu.com: Host not found
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: Connection timed out
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0

Comment: It seems like your desktop can't reach the keyserver. Are you behind a firewall or proxy?

If you are behind a firewall you can try running `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 6AF0E1940624A220`
If you are behind a proxy, you can use `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver-options http-proxy=myProxy --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 6AF0E1940624A220`. Make sure you fill in **myProxy**.