# Which sqlite database uses new Skype for Linux?

Tags: skype, sqlite, sqlite3

Skype for Linux version 4.3 stores data on `~/.Skype/<user>/main.db`.
I installed recently a new version 5.5.0.1 that changes completely its GUI.

*Note:* I also tested [Skype Insider](https://www.skype.com/en/insider/) version 8.x.x.x, and somehow worked but finally got uninstalled due to a dependency on libstdc++.so.6 (I think `aptitude` complained and hitting Y uninstalled it, or something similar).

The point is that the new Skype does not store data on that `main.db`.
Or at least that is what I experienced doing some tests.
I realized that there exists other `main.db` now under `~/.config/skypeforlinux/skylib/<user>/main.db`, but it is empty.

So for the moment, I am starting two Skype instances, one of 4.3 and one of 5.5.

Does anyone can explain how the new Skype works regarding storing data on sqlite3?

Comment: Now what?
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/skype_linux-skype_startms-skype_installms/end-of-life-of-skype-for-linux-43/70fe7036-ddf3-4fa3-9c06-1bca3ec0226c?auth=1

Answer (score 1):

From the Skype for Linux forum site: [Skype for Linux - main.db is not updated](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/skype_linux-skype_messms-skype_instamessms/skype-for-linux-maindb-is-not-updated/1dba1a50-eff8-4ef3-9d60-596e0c0d8131)

Quoting **Van_M**, Skype Community Moderator:

> Moving forward the messages that you will send / receive through this new Skype version will be stored in the cloud for two years.
>   However, the older conversation will not carry over on the new Skype application.
>
> Hope this information helps.
>
> Thanks.
>
> Van_M
>   Skype Community Moderator

So it seems that the **new Skype application (versions 5.5 & 8.10) does NOT store anymore a local sqlite database** having messages, contacts, conversation, etc...